# Checking function pointers type

Tags: c++, c, pointers

Let define a structure `parser`  :

```
struct parser {
    int (*buffer_push_strategy)();
    int (*escape_buffer_push_strategy)();
    int (*do_callback_strategy)();
};
```

I have an initialization function :

```
int parser_init() {    
    if (some_condition) {
        parser->buffer_push_strategy = buffer_push_strategy1;
        parser->escape_buffer_push_strategy = escape_buffer_push_strategy1;
        parser->do_callback_strategy = do_callback_strategy1;
    }
    else {
        parser->buffer_push_strategy = buffer_push_strategy2;
        parser->escape_buffer_push_strategy = escape_buffer_push_strategy2;
        parser->do_callback_strategy = do_callback_strategy2;
    }
return 0;
}
```

where the strategy functions are defined somewhere.

Ok, so my interest is to determine which strategy has been used when I write the unit tests. Any idea how to accomplish that?

I saw something on internet about `is_pointer` function from `C++ 11`, but I don`t think this would help me.

Comment: parser is a type, not a variable. Remove typedef in the first piece of code.

Comment: @AntonioGarrido Yes sorry

Comment: I am not sure about the question... Are you looking for something like: `int strategy= (parser->buffer_push_strategy == buffer_push_strategy1) ? 1 : 2;`

Comment: Yes @AntonioGarrido, something like that, in my test I write something like `REQUIRE(parser->buffer_push_strategy == buffer_push_strategy1)` when `some_cond` is `true`;

Comment: Your new code still has the same problem. Again, you are defining the type parser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parser is a variable:

```
struct parserT {
    int (*buffer_push_strategy)();
    int (*escape_buffer_push_strategy)();
    int (*do_callback_strategy)();
} parser;
```

If you want to know which the strategy is, you could use:

```
int strategy= (parser->buffer_push_strategy == buffer_push_strategy1) ? 1 : 2;
```

Perhaps, you prefer to store the strategy number:

```
int parser_init() {    
    if (some_condition) {
        parser->buffer_push_strategy = buffer_push_strategy1;
        parser->escape_buffer_push_strategy = escape_buffer_push_strategy1;
        parser->do_callback_strategy = do_callback_strategy1;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        parser->buffer_push_strategy = buffer_push_strategy2;
        parser->escape_buffer_push_strategy = escape_buffer_push_strategy2;
        parser->do_callback_strategy = do_callback_strategy2;
        return 2;
    }
}
```

Then, you could init the parser as:

```
const int STRATEGY= parser_init();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can compare function pointers

```
if(p.buffer_push_strategy == buffer_push_strategy1)
```

See https://ideone.com/QQzL1c